# Proper file permissions for (locally) shared Dropbox folder

Tags: permissions, docker, dropbox

I have a shared mounted Dropbox folder running in a container.

What is the correct way to set the Dropbox user and group so that two different users on the computer can both read and write the files?

I'm using the `janeczku/dropbox` container, if that matters.

I tried running it as group `dropbox`, and added that group to both users, but we still get permission errors.